# Unserialize an object which had properties with different level of access

Tags: php, oop, object, serialization

I had a class that had this kind of definition:

```
class AClass {
    private $member;
}
```

I was serializing and unserializing this class in different pages and it worked fine.

Now for some reasons I had to change the class definition to something like this:

```
class AClass {
    public $member;
}
```

Now when unserializing I get a null $member value instead of the value stored in the serialize string.

It would be hard to give a working example as this requires two execution cycles but it can be synthesized like this: https://3v4l.org/eTp6j .

What is the best way to fix this issue? The only one I am thinking about right now would be to just edit the serialized string which seems like a sloppy hack.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a working example ?

Comment: I think this would be hard as it would imply two execution cycles. One that would define the first type of class with private level of access to that member which serialises the object and another execution which defines the second type of class with public level of access to that member which tries to unserialise.

Comment: Anyway, something like this - https://3v4l.org/eTp6j

Comment: Editing the serialized string might seem like a sloppy hack but it's probably also the best way, unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps restore the property visibility to private in the class definition so that unserialize works again, but providing magic __get()/__set() methods to make it publicly accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the serialized string in the database but I had to know which classes had their properties access level changed. You can do that in a batch for the whole database but as we dump old results after some time, I've chosen to modify the serialized string on-the-fly.

```
<?php

function newUnserializeFunction($response)
{
    // Edit string
    $classes = [
        ATest::class
    ];

    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        do {
            // Private class name
            $result = replaceClassPrivateProtectedToPublic("\0" . $class . "\0", $response);
        } while ($result);
        do {
            // Protected class name
            $result = replaceClassPrivateProtectedToPublic("\0*\0" . $class . "\0*\0", $response);
        } while ($result);
    }

    // Unserialize
    $return = \unserialize($response);

    return $return;
}

function replaceClassPrivateProtectedToPublic($className, &$content)
{
    $classNameWithSlashes = preg_quote($className, '/');
    $result = preg_match('/(([\d]+)\:\"' . $classNameWithSlashes . '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if($result && count($matches) >= 4) {
        $lengthOffset = $matches[2][1];
        $lengthLength = strlen($matches[2][0]);

        $length = strlen($matches[3][0]);

        // Replace the class name
        $content = preg_replace('/'.$classNameWithSlashes.'/', '', $content, 1);

        // Replace the class name length
        $content = substr_replace($content, $length, $lengthOffset, $lengthLength);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change class definition and hope that everything will be fine. 
When member is **private** serialized string looks like:

`string(53) "O:5:"ATest":1:{s:13:"ATestmember";s:9:"something";}"`

and when member is **public** - serialized string is:

`string(45) "O:5:"ATest":1:{s:6:"member";s:9:"something";}"`

That's why you get `null` - you can't access private member from outside.
Solution would be to update serialized string's in database - by removing `ATest` class name part from field definitions.